Author of 'alphabeta'
Anyone familiar with rabbi and or scholar that had a work called "alphabeta" or "alefbeta" (not rabbi Fohrman) who may have passed away within the last ten or twenty years, or less?

Are you thinking of the Alpha Beta books by Shmuel Ashkenazi (he died about 4-5 years ago)? (אלפא ביתא קדמייתא/תנייתא ששמואל זעירא)

Yes! Thank you!

Here are R' Shmuel Ashkenazi's two Alfa Beta books:
אלפא ביתא קדמיתא דשמואל זעירא (Alfa Beta Kadmita de-Shmuel Zeira)
אלפא ביתא תניתא דשמואל זעירא (Alfa Beta Tanita de-Shmuel Zeira)
For more information on him, see here and here.
